# Define global alias for static classes

Tags: c#, static, alias

I have a static `ExceptionHelper` that looks like this:

```
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    public static async void ShowDialog(string message)
    {
        // Show message
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to call this method I do it like this at the moment:

```
ExceptionHelper.ShowDialog("This is a message.");
```

I now thought of defining an alias for the `ExceptionHelper` to not having to write the whole word each time I want to use it.

I know I can achieve it with `using`:

```
using Ex = MyNamespaces.ExceptionHelper;
```

But then I'd have to define it in each file I want to use the method. Is there a way I can define the alias globally without changing the name of the class? Or is there any attribute I can set above the class declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Extension Method

You could make it an extension method on string.

```
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    public static async void ShowDialog(this string message)
    {
        // Show message
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
using WhateverNamespaceExceptionHelperLivesIn;

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        "This is a message".ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This makes your question moot - you don't have to define an alias at all.

### Static imports

An alternative approach is to import the class statically. You won't need an alias, because you can reference the `ShowDialog` method directly. This will require C#6/Visual Studio 2015.

```
using static WhateverNamespaceExceptionHelperLivesIn.ExceptionHelper;

public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        ShowDialog("This is a message");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of C# 10, you can now define gloabl usings.

```
// GlobalUsing.cs
global using static WhateverNamespaceExceptionHelperLivesIn.ExceptionHelper;
```

And it will now be available globally, without having to define the class name, or the namespace, at the top of each class.

```
// Available Globally in the Project
public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        ShowDialog("This is a message");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# 6.0 you can use static usings:

```
using static MyNamespace.ExceptionHelper;
```

Of course not globally, that works only for defines. But in a file where you use this line, you can use the members of the `ExceptionHelper` without any prefix.

Comment: That's true. Nevertheless I'd have to add this `using` to every file.

Answer (score 0):

This might apply, even though you are using a method. You could use an ENUM type instead that lies outside of any namespace and access globals values that way. Place the enum in a file outside of any namespace. You can access it globally that way, or if you have trouble, using the "global" keyword below if you have any trouble referencing it:

```
enum Size
{
SMALL = 1,
MEDIUM = 5,
LARGE = 10
}

class Test {
    int mysize1 = (int)Size.SMALL;
    int mysize2 = (int)global::Size.MEDIUM;
}
```